# apply tick to checkbox that extends beyond border

Tags: css, checkbox

When checkbox is selected, we would like to apply a tick *which extends beyond the checkbox* area. Applying background image does not work since it cannot extend beyond the checkbox area.

So, I thought of creating nested spans and applying background image to the outer span. However, the tick image gets hidden by the inner span.

Quick jsfiddle (does not show the image) is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/joshbay84/ux284fsy/)

```
<span class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
  </span>
</span>

span.inner{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color:yellow;
}

span.outer{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-top:1px;
  background-color:orange;
  background-image:url('sometickimage.png');
}
```

Basically, the tick gets hidden by the span with yellow background.

Is there a way to achieve this without absolute positioning?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `z-index` it makes an element stays on top of another like this `z-index:100;`

Comment: there is not html for tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using CSS pseudo classes. Tweak as per your need!

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666666;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
label:before {
  line-height: 20px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before,
label:hover:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
label:hover:before {
  color: #d5d5d5;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Morning">
  <label for="check1">Morning</label>
  <br>
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Evening">
  <label for="check2">Evening</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox69" class="css-checkbox lrg" checked="checked">
<label for="checkbox69" name="checkbox69_lbl" class="css-label lrg out"> A tick which is going out of the checkbox </label>
```

With the CSS associated :

```
label {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
  position: absolute; 
overflow: hidden; 
clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
height:1px; 
width:1px; 
margin:-1px; 
padding:0;
border:0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
padding-left:20px;
height:15px; 
display:inline-block;
line-height:15px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
font-size:15px;
vertical-align:middle;
cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.css-label{
background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/dark-check-      green.png);
}

.vlad{background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/vlad.png);}



input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox.sme:checked + label.css-label.sme{

 background-position: 0 -16px;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox.lrg + label.css-label.lrg {
padding-left:22px;
height:20px; 
display:inline-block;
line-height:20px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
font-size:15px;
vertical-align:middle;
cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox.lrg:checked + label.css-label.lrg{

background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me in Jfiddle as well.

Some things may be not relevant in the code, try to delete some parts and test the checkbox to see if it is or not